# Children modules with devided routing modules

Tags: angular, routes, router

My angular application is based on https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron
The way they define and load modules though the router-module is kinda different from what you can find on internet.

This is a devided routing processus template, and I decided to continue by this way.

---

- For each component, a new module is created, defining a routing-module.
- The `AppModule` loads all sub-mobules and the routes are etablished automatically.

> app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    HomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

As you can see, the `HomeComponent` is not defined in the `routing-module`.
It's defined in a sub-module like below.

> home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [HomeRoutingModule]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

And it's working as expected.

---

**My question is, how can reproduce this processus for children modules of the** `HomeModule`
I have multiple views in my home page with a sub-menu.
I tried to do it like written below, but the page is not found.

> home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [NewsModule, HomeRoutingModule]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

> home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'news'
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

> news.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NewsComponent],
  imports: [NewsRoutingModule]
})
export class NewsModule {}
```

> news-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'news',
    component: NewsComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NewsRoutingModule {}
```

---

My news module html contains a `<router-outlet>` balise, so it's not the problem.  I can see my PageNotFound properly.

Any idea?

Comment: at first glance it looks like your method of handling lazy modules should not load modules code in separate request and all is loaded when app.module is loaded are you sure code for additional modules is lazy loaded?

Comment: it was an assumption, I maybe should have called it `decentralized` routing modules

Comment: @Xesenix do you understand my problem? I can add additional informations if you need it

Comment: I read through it few times and I am not totally sure where lays your problem maybe some stackblitz example would help to visualize it better. For now, it looks to me that you are trying to use RouterModule.forChild in some invalid way

Comment: I think the problem comes from the path of `news-routing.module.ts`. Since it's not defined in the children of the `home-routing` module, the route is badly generated, I guess. Instead to be interpreted as `/home/news`, it's maybe done as `/news`

Comment: yes that's what I mean usually forChild is called from lazy-loaded module and there is some context there to know what would be root for routing. And when you skip lazy loading im not sure how that suppose to know where to put the routing.

Comment: I tried to replace `redirectTo: 'news'` by `redirectTo: '/news'` and the page is found. So ye, it's just not considered as a child. I couldn't find a Routes property to say, this path is a child path, you know?

Comment: you could use full path instead of just `/news` you put `/home/news` but i gues that kind of kills purpose of spliting thos routings. Other way you can use children property of routing configuration

Comment: yea, I will just go for the normal way, defining my paths and components directly in the home-routing module, thanks for you help